# My laptop won't start. CUPS scheduler failed to start

Tags: boot, printing

It happens when i restart my laptop because it's fine before.

```
[  OK  ] Started Show Plymouth Boot Screen.
[  OK  ] Started Forward Password Rs to Plymouth Directory Watch.
[  OK  ] Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[  OK  ] Listening on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Watch.
         Starting Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status...
[  OK  ] Created slice System-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
         Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight...
[  OK  ] Started Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
[  OK  ] Finished Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight.
```

etc

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Network Manager Wait Online.Profiles...nager.e the ppp link was shut down...
[FAILED] Failed to start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
[FAILED] Failed to start CUPS Scheduler.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
[FAILED] Failed to start CUPS Scheduler.
[FAILED] Failed to start CUPS Scheduler.
[FAILED] Failed to start CUPS Scheduler.
[FAILED] Failed to start CUPS Scheduler.
```

I get this message after i try to fixed unmet dependency (with dist-upgrade) and restart it. Can i fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide detailed information about the "unmet dependency" and exactly what you did to try and fix it.

Comment: [This] (https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) is what i did.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not booting while connected to a corporate LAN, I would suggest doing this:

1. Boot into "Recovery Mode"
2. Open a terminal
3. Disable the Network Manager wait:
   `sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager-wait-online.service`
4. Reboot

This should resolve the issue. The CUPS Scheduler may still fail, but it should start properly after booting when the device is connected to the local network.

Comment: I have another problem with recovery mode. I uploaded it on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/LDBUTlyv8Xg) if you don't mind.